# Email Template Replace merge field

Tags: apex, email-template, string

I have an email template which uses merge fields from a custom object. For reasons difficult to explain here, I have to write my own code to read the body of the email template in Apex, replace merge fields with the objects field value. For eg:

```
plainTextBody.replaceAll('{!File_User__c.Name}', fileUser.Name);
```

However, this throws an exception

```
System.StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition {!File_User__c.Name}
```

I search on the net and the resolution is to escape the curly braces. I have tried using \{!File_User__c.Name\} but it doesn't work.

My questions are
1. How to we parse merge fields without the error above?
2. Is there a better way of parsing email template?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_replaceAll.htm

The document for ReplaceAll method of string functions

and document for replace method of string functions

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_replace.htm

So ReplaceAll expects a regex .For your case i would suggest you to use simple replace and should satisfy the requirement

```
plainTextBody.replace('{!File_User__c.Name}', fileUser.Name);
```

All the matching substrings of the string will be replaced

Comment: Thank you. Replace works. So I will have to basically run a loop while the match is found and replace the strings. That would  work as of now.

Comment: hey no need to run any loop as i mentioned .Just use replace and you should be good.wherever the string is found it will automatically replace .Hope this helped you

Comment: What if I have multiple email templates with different merge field values?